# NLog webservice target, slack icon based on log level

Tags: nlog

I'm new to NLog, and fighting with finding the solution to what I'm going for.

I'd like warning and up to get pushed to a slack channel with log level specific icons.  I have got that working, technically. I have 2 pairs of targets/loggers that are hard coded to catch warnings only, and errors and above, and have 'warning' or 'error' icons hard coded into the layout template.

```xml
<target xsi:type="WebService"
        name="slackWarningTarget"
        url="https://hooks.slack.com/services/xx/xx/xx"
        protocol="JsonPost"
        encoding="utf-8"
        >

  <parameter name="text" type="System.String" layout=":warning: ${machinename} ${message}"/>
  <parameter name="channel" type="System.String" layout="xx"/>
</target>
```

and

```xml
<logger name="*" minlevel="Warn" maxlevel="Warn" writeTo="slackWarningTarget">
```

Is there a way to better accomplish this?  I want warning level to map to :warning:, etc.

I'd also like some info level stuff pushed there as well.  To do this I created a named logger that always logs to the slack channel, but it results in duplicated messages if they are warning or above.

```xml
<logger name="noticeLogger" writeTo="slackInfoTarget" />
```

I'd guess there is a much more elegant way to do both of these things than i have come up with on my own.

Answer (score 0):

You could do that from config with a [${when}](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/When-Layout-Renderer), e.g.

```
layout="${when:when=${level}=='Warn':inner=\:warning\::else:${when:when=${level}== 'Error':inner=\:error\::else:todo}}"
```

but it get clumsy fast.

Another option is to register a custom layout renderer:

```cs
// register in the start of your program (e.g. main, app_start)
// usage ${slackIcon}
LayoutRenderer.Register("slackIcon", logEvent =>
{
    if (logEvent.Level == LogLevel.Warn)
    {
        return ":warning:";
    }
    if (logEvent.Level == LogLevel.Error)
    {
        return ":error:";
    }

    return ":other:";
    //etc
});
```

See [How to write a custom layout renderer](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/How-to-write-a-custom-layout-renderer)